# ImportPhotos generates Errors

Tags: qgis, import, photos

I'm trying to get a layer with all my Photolocations. The Importphotos plug-in doesn't work. It just generates a `ZeroDivisionError`.

```
line 338, in ok
    lat, lon = self.get_exif_location(tags, "lonlat")
line 492, in get_exif_location
    lat = self._convert_to_degress(gps_latitude)
line 471, in _convert_to_degress
    d = float(value.values[0].num) / float(value.values[0].den)
ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero.
```

How do you resolve this divide by zero error?

I am using QGIS 3.2.0 Bonn and Python 3.6.0

EDIT: I just tried Las Palmas with photo2shape and it works without any problems.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the inbuilt "import geotagged photos" algorithm from the processing toolbox instead.

Answer (score 0):

I have had success adding the markers for the location of the photos using the inbuilt feature and something I thought was useful you can set the marker as a triangle or arrow and set the rotation to the direction of the photo so the marker points the way the camera was pointed. But I can't figure out how to add a preview of the photo if you click/scroll over the marker.  Is that possible with the inbuilt version?  I played around a little and found a widget menu but couldn't get it to work.  I also installed importphotos plugin but can't find it in the vector menu and the buttons don't appear on the toolbars.  Anyone have a similar issue?